# How can I enable / disable QTableWidget's horizontal / vertical header?

Tags: python, header, pyqt, qtablewidget

If I set the horizontalHeaderVisible or verticalHeaderVisible attribute to false in Qt Designer, this works fine. But how can I enable / disable headers in my code? I've been trying something like this:

```
self.ui.tblContents.horizontalHeaderVisible = False
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You'd get the header and `.hide()` (or `.setVisible(False)`:

```
self.ui.tblContents.horizontalHeader().hide()
# or
# self.ui.tblContents.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)

self.ui.tblContents.verticalHeader().hide()
# or
# self.ui.tblContents.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
```

Answer (score 10):

In case you want to do that using QTableWidget() for Python37 PyQt5.
Here are the steps to hide both Vertical and Horizontal:

#### Initialize the widget, I mentioned it to make it easy on you to locate:

```
self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
```

#### the steps:

#### Hide Horizontal header

```
self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
```

#### Hide vertical header

```
self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for this. Worked perfect for me in PyQt5.

Some screenshots for people to visualize this if confused.

Vertical ones (for row numbers) disabled:

```
self.tableView = QTableView()
self.tableView.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
```

[image]

Horizontal one disabled:

```
self.tableView = QTableView()
self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
```

[image]

With both vertical and horizontal headers disabled.

```
self.tableView = QTableView()
self.tableView.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
```

[image]