# How to remove/hide the row count in QTableWidget?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget

How can I remove/hide the row count in QTableWidget?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I enable / disable QTableWidget's horizontal / vertical header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910136/how-can-i-enable-disable-qtablewidgets-horizontal-vertical-header)

Comment: `your_tablewidget.verticalHeader().hide()`

Answer (score 0):

`self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)`

This will help you hide the header.